# How would I make a Python3 file with argparse that would read the contents of a file?

Tags: python, linux, bash, argparse

I'm kind of a Python noob at the moment as I've only been using it for a a few days and I was wondering how would you write a Python script that uses argparse to read the contents of a file containing numerous URLs and set the contents as a variable? For example:

```
root@user:~# python myscript.py -f "URLs.txt"
```

and the python shell would then print the variable

```
URLs = The contents of the file
print(URLs)
```

resulting in:

```
root@user:~# python myscript.py -f "URLs.txt"
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/
root@user:~#
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: whats your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start I'd recommend:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo')
args = parser.parse_args()
with open(args.foo, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    print(lines)
```

which with a ramdom file in my directory produces:

```
0029:~/mypy$ python stack47119114.py -f foo.txt
    1,    2,     
    3,    4,    5
```

We could use a `argparse.FileType` to open the file as well, but the `with open` syntax is preferable.  For a larger problem I'd put the `parse_args` in a `if __name__...` block, and define the action in a function.

But the basic point is that `argparse` should be used primarily has a parser, not the full action code.  Its purpose is to find out what your user wants.  In a real problem, acting on that input is the job of functions and classes that are defined separately (maybe even in an imported module).

Comment: Confirmed this answer works with Python 3.6 on Linux (WSL).